# Is Oracle Workspace Manager production ready?

Tags: temporal-database

I'm exploring options for implementing a large-scale temporal database. There will likely be billions of records managed with minimal temporal churn, and I'd like a vendor implemented solution to avoid placing too much responsibility in the application(s) that will populate, update, and query the warehouse.

Oracle Workspace Manager is one potential solution I'm looking at, but I've gotten the impression from online research that OWM isn't practical for a production system. Does anyone have any experience with using OWM for a temporal database, in particular using the TSQL2 constructs?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard that PostgreSQL has a decent support for bi-temporal databases so you may try to do something with it.

*I'm currently also trying to find the best way to implement a large-scale database, and am making you question my favorite.*